# Applying .scss-styles to vuetify custom tags

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, vuetify.js

There I have a PageHeader.vue file in my project which includes a stylesheet from an external PageHeader.scss-file:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <v-toolbar
      app
      flat
      style="height: 300px;">
    </v-toolbar>
    <div id="logo"></div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
  import './../assets/css/PageHeader.scss'
  export default {
    name: 'PageHeader'
  }
</script>
```

If I do so everything goes well, but if I try to remove this line:

```
style="height: 300px;"
```

and instead use the style in my .scss-file like this:

```
v-toolbar {
  height: 300px;
}
```

then my style from .scss-file does not apply. But if I prepend

> v-toolbar

with the point symbol (treating it like a class but not like a tag name) it works good:

```
.v-toolbar {
  height: 300px;
}
```

But I do have the v-toolbar TAG in my markup inside the .vue-file, NOT A DIV with  "v-loobar" classname. Is there any way to work with vuetify custom tags the same way as with regular HTML tags?

Comment: The actual html of the page doesn't have a `v-toolbar` element, Vue renders that into html content based on the component template. So you could add a class to the `v-toolbar` template, but there is not a `v-toolbar` element anywhere once Vue runs.

Answer (score 1):

The `v-toolbar` component renders to

```
<nav class="v-toolbar" ...></nav>
```

So you could style the `nav` element with something like `nav.v-toolbar {...}`.